# How can I set values in the $conf array using the admin interface?

Tags: configuration

I am using the [Journal](http://drupal.org/project/journal)  module and in order to limit the forms its text box appears on the form ids have to go into a $conf variable. The docs say it has to go into settings.php but I don't watch that.

```
$conf['journal_form_ids'] = array(
    'fivestar_custom_widget' => 0,
    'guestbook_form_entry_form' => 0,
    'imagefield_js' => 0,
    'img_assist_header_form' => 0,
    'img_assist_properties_form' => 0,
    'link_widget_js' => 0,
    ...
);
```

Is there a module that can accomplish this from the admin interface?
Can it be done through some kind of execute PHP form like with devel?

**It has to be done from the admin**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you can do this at `devel/php` if Devel module is enabled and you have access to Devel module's `Execute PHP code`.

The PHP to do what you want is

```
variable_set('journal_form_ids', array(
    'fivestar_custom_widget' => 0,
    'guestbook_form_entry_form' => 0,
    'imagefield_js' => 0,
    'img_assist_header_form' => 0,
    'img_assist_properties_form' => 0,
    'link_widget_js' => 0,
    // ...
  ));
```

Comment: I worked it out about 15 minutes ago. I needs to set up some answer notifications on SE ;)

Comment: Mostly I use `drush vset` from CLI  - worth looking into!